# Phaser: Stroke to text is getting blur on browser screen and images getting pixelated

Tags: html, html5-canvas, game-engine, phaser-framework

I am new to Phaser 2. I have some issues.

**1-** When I am printing text on screen the text and its stroke is getting blur. What should I do now. Text is looking ugly

**2-** Even my high resolution images are getting pixelated. I don't know why but I think it is because of scaling the images `this.imageName.scale.setTo(0.4, 0.4);` There is some concept of **DPI**. But I don't know. Should I apply it on each and every images or only once on the html file only.

Please help? I am stuck.